# How do I teach mypy about my class decorator?

Tags: python-decorators, mypy

I wrote a class decorator that adds an `__init__` method to its class argument, and the `__init__` method adds an attribute to the class. Mypy does not recognize either, and raises an error when I use them. However, when the `dataclass` decorator does the same, mypy recognizes both correctly. This is the code:

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int

# Attributes and methods added by @dataclass are recognized by mypy
foo = Foo(1)
print(foo.x)

def my_decorator(cls):
    def init(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    setattr(cls, '__init__', init)
    return cls

@my_decorator
class Bar:
    pass

# error: Too many arguments for "Bar"  [call-arg]
bar = Bar(2)
# error: "Bar" has no attribute "x"  [attr-defined]
print(bar.x)
```

`mypy --version` prints `mypy 1.6.1 (compiled: yes)`

How can I teach mypy about the transformations performed by my decorator?

Comment: You're yet another person looking for Intersection type. See the duplicate and also check out [basedmypy](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) and [this python/typing issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) for much more details.

Answer (score 0):

mypy does not run your code - it does *static* analysis. So I don't think this is possible. But why not just subclass instead of using a decorator?

Comment: Upon further research, it appears to be possible by creating a mypy plugin, but the process is experimental and poorly documented. Subclassing is not sufficient for some purposes, dataclass being an example.